# Calling event click with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

It is possible to call a event click with JavaScript? how?

I'm trying to call this event when a button get clicked.

I'm creating Buttons dynamically so the id's change constantly

Here is how i make the buttons dynamically and assign the event click

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "showAndHide();", true);

            Button Btn_clic = (Button)sender;
            var name = Btn_clic.Text;

            List.ListUsers listArea = new List.ListUsers();
            List<Data.Area> Area = listArea.AreaList();

            List<Data.Area> ListOfEquiposOk = Area.Where(x => x.AREA == name && x.STANDBY == 0).ToList();

            List<Button> Botones = new List<Button>();

            var TeamFCH = ListOfEquiposOk.Select(x => x.TEAM).Distinct().ToList();

            foreach (var team in TeamFCH)
            {
                Button newButton = new Button();
                newButton.CommandName = "Btn" + Convert.ToString(team);
                newButton.ID = "Btn_" + Convert.ToString(team);
                newButton.Text = team;
                newButton.CommandArgument = name;

                newButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(newButton_Click);


                Botones.Add(newButton);

                GoodPanel.Controls.Add(newButton);
                newButton.CssClass = "btn-primary outline separate";
            }
        }

protected void newButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "ModalGood();", true);

            Button Btnclick = (Button)sender;
            var team = Btnclick.Text;
            string name = Btnclick.CommandArgument;

            List.ListUsers listArea = new List.ListUsers();
            List<Data.Area> Area = listArea.AreaList();

            List<Data.Area> ListOfToolsOk = Area.Where(x => x.AREA == name && x.TEAM == team && x.STANDBY == 0).ToList();

            var ToolArea = ListOfToolsOk.Select(x => x.TEAM);
            Grv_Eng.DataSource = ListOfToolsOk;
            Grv_Eng.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: You meant Java instead of JavaScript?

Comment: Then why not add it to the button? `<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="newButton_Click" />`. If you have done that @Aenadon's answer should work.

Comment: @Adrián nop, i really mean JavaScript

Comment: My bad I didn't read ScriptManager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to assign a OnClick event, do it like this.

```
Button Btnclick = new Button();
Btnclick.Click += newButton_Click;
Btnclick.Text = "MyButton";
Btnclick.ID = "MyButtonID";

PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(Btnclick);
```

And if you want to reference the dynamic ID, use `FindControl` and `ClientID` on the aspx page.

```
document.getElementById("<%= PlaceHolder1.FindControl("MyButtonID").ClientID %>").click
```

Comment: i have like this but my event doesn't fire, i don't know why you can look at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44905518/event-click-doesnt-get-fired?noredirect=1#comment76790267_44905518

Comment: Probably because you need to assign the click on EVERY page load, and that includes a PostBack. So if you assign the `Click` in another Button event, then you must make sure you execute it again at next page load.

Comment: so in the page_load i need to put the event like `Event(sender, e)`?

Comment: I tested your snippet. It works. Just put it in `Page_load`. And start by getting one button to work and work from there. And don't store buttons in a List, that makes no sense. Also if you want to use `CommandArgument`, you need to assign a `Command`, not a `Click`

Comment: what did you recommend instead the list of buttons? i use because in my XML there are many "TEAMS" so these is why the list

Comment: but the list that i have first takes data from the data base (I'm newest in asp.net, i know that these doesn't justify at all)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148357/discussion-between-cesg-dav-and-vdwwd).

Answer (score 0):

Assign an onClick listener to your button.

```
document.getElementById("your-id").click = function () {
    newButton_Click();
}
```

Comment: I'm creating the buttons dynamically, so the id change constantly

Comment: Add when creating the button.

Comment: or use document.getElementsByClassName() / .getElementsByTagName()

Comment: @Daniel i add when i create the buttons

Answer (score 0):

Here you go try this for dynamically created buttons

```
$(document).on('click', '#id', function(){});
```

Comment: if your id's change everytime assign a class to them and just replace #id with .className

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `data-` attribute to id the buttons from javascript and then you just attach to the javascript event:

So, from the server side you can do this:

```
 newButton.Attributes["data-dynamic-button"] = team;
```

And you can implement this on the client side:

```
$("[data-dynamic-button]").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    alert($(event.currentTarget).data("dynamic-button"));
});
```